# mySQL Query with a LIMIT on a row value

Tags: mysql, group-by, limits

I am trying to replace a lot of queries like this with a single query.

```
SELECT * FROM y WHERE x = a ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 50
SELECT * FROM y WHERE x = b ORDER by timestamp LIMIT 50
SELECT * FROM y WHERE x = c ORDER by timestamp LIMIT 50
SELECT * FROM y WHERE x = d ORDER by timestamp LIMIT 50
SELECT * FROM y WHERE x = .....
```

- This is to display a kanban style column board with 50 ordered results for each column
- SELET * FROM y ORDER by timestamp would return 100k to 1M rows so too slow to limit in code.
- I want to get the first 50 results for each value of X (there maybe 100 values of X and therefore currently 100 queries)
- Order is important
- It's not clear to me that GROUP BY can help here.

Comment: If a stored procedure is a viable solution, you could create a temporary table, insert the IDs of the ~200 records, then query the table on just the records where IDs exist in the temporary table 

Comment: This is all dynamic, i.e. the actual query will have a range of criteria that change regularly (including the ordering) so I don't think this can help.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Do you have an index on `(x, timestamp)`? That is far more important than rewriting from 4 queries to 1.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ it's not 4 queries (x might have 100 values) typically the query is doing a full table scan (because there are a dozen where clauses not shown here) so  its more important to do the query once in a single full table scan instead of lots; but then reduce the number of results sent to the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a reasonable new version of MySQL you can use a window function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT y.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY ts) as rn 
    FROM y
    WHERE x IN (a,b,c,d)
) AS t
WHERE rn <= 50
ORDER BY ts
```

Comment: This is excellent and exactly what we want from what we can tell. We need to do some performance testing. We have some deployments on Aurora which is now very behind mySQL so that's somewhat problematic!

Comment: If you are on an older version you can mimic window functions with variables: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/  If you look for a definition of an hack you may end up on that page:-)

Comment: Upvoted, but FWIW there's no estimated date for a version of Aurora that supports MySQL 8.0 features.

Comment: I would be interested to hear about the speed.  I suspect that it will collect lots of rows in the derived table, only to filter out most of them with the `rn <= 50`.

Comment: @RickJames it seems like that should be a lot quicker than returning all the results to the client. We are working on some tests :)